# Issue with $state.go() transitions, only on second click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a issue with ui-router which I can't quite put my finger on. I can click on a link (on the login page of my app) and navigate to a second page (one where the user can register). There is a cancel button on the second page which simply navigates the user back to the first page. All good so far.

If I then click on the same link again, the user appears to stay on the same page (i.e. the login page), however I have added a 'state change' handler to my app (it just logs the transition to the console) and can see that what actually happens is that the app seems to transition to the second page and then back again. The following won't make much sense other than to demonstrate the flow. You can see the state change start, end and the view load before it starts again and transitions back to 'authentication.login'

```
Start state change : {authentication.login} to {authentication.registration}
View content loading
End state change success : {authentication.login} to {authentication.registration}
View content loaded
Start state change : {authentication.registration} to {authentication.login}
View content loading
End state change success : {authentication.registration} to {authentication.login}
View content loaded
```

NOTE: both pages are siblings of the same abstract node.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

NOTE: state config is as follows

```
.state("authentication", {
    url : "/auth",
    abstract : "true",
    templateUrl : "app/main/common/html/templates/simple-template.html",
})

.state("authentication.login", {
    url: "/login",
    views: {
        "main": {
            templateUrl : "app/main/authentication/html/login.html",
            controller: "LoginController"
        }
    }
})

.state("authentication.registration", {
    url: "/registration",
    views: {
        "main": {
            templateUrl : "app/main/authentication/html/registration.html",
            controller: "RegistrationController"
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have any 
    rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'
logic in your app that is causing the state transition.
Usually logic will be put in here to kick a user back to the login page if the user is not auth'd
a wild guess but the best guess i can make given the information provided.
thanks

another idea, if you remove the state change handler does everything work ok?

Comment: I was pretty sure we didn't but just to be sure I checked. The only $stateChangeStart references I can see are in my own state change handler which just logs state changes to the console (and the angular libs of course). I use my handler as a debugging tool occasionally. 

To be certain this was not causing a problem I removed it completely from the module. Still get the same behaviour. I'll update the main question with the config for these two screens just in case I have done something wrong.

Thanks

Comment: i believe i am right in saying an abstract state does not exist per se but is used for providing common config for all child states. I think this is saying authentication.login and authentication.registration will use the same template defined in the abstract state. There is no point in defining the URL for the abstract state however (if my thinking is correct) since both children override it. However, not sure this is causing the problem you are experiencing. Also should "true" be quoted?